# How to format numbers by inserting a space between each group of three digits?

Tags: php

I use preg replace to separate numbers by inserting a space between each group of three digits:

```
$alexa_rank_raw = 8389876;

$alexa_rank = preg_replace("/(\d{3})/", '$1.', $alexa_rank_raw);

// alexa rank becomes: 838.987.6
```

How can I do the replace so the final number would look like this:

**8.389.876**

Any ideas?

Comment: Ummm...by running the same `preg_replace` above on the reversal of `$alexa_rank_raw`, and then reversing the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
$rank = number_format($alexa_rank_raw, 0, ",", ".");
```

But here's also a regex version, because why not?

```
$rank = preg_replace('/(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+$)/', '$1.', $alexa_rank_raw);
```

How it works: it matches groups of up to three digits greedily (as many as possible up to three), but uses positive lookahead to assert that there is an exact multiple of three digits starting from the position where the matched group ends all the way up to the end of the input.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/SBDoqa)**.

Comment: You should do `number_format($alexa_rank_raw, 0, '', '.');` instead so there are no added 0's.